# How to use one Webview for a bottomactuvity

Tags: java, android, webview

I want to create an app like Ali express. An app for an online store. I am using the bottom navigation activity in android studio with Java language but I don't know how to use the webview so that if any of the bottom activity is clicked it would display a particular URL. For instance, the home, categories, cart.

[image]

Comment: for me and everyone please add more details what do you want. what you have tried so far post your code of your `xml` and `java` so we can give more accurate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code :

In Xml add webview according to you for example like this:

```
<WebView
    <!-- covers 368dp width as required. -->
    android:layout_width="368dp"
      
    <!-- unique ID of WebView -->
    android:id="@+id/web"
      
    <!-- covers 495dp height as required. -->
    android:layout_height="495dp"/>
```

In Java add this :

```
    WebView w = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
      
    // loading http://www.google.com url in the the WebView.
    w.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
      
    // this will enable the javascipt.
    w.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      
    // WebViewClient allows you to handle 
    // onPageFinished and override Url loading.
    w.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

for more information visit [Web View Documention](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#AddingWebView)

#### OUTPUT :

[image]

Comment: OK. But I want to put one webview I to be accessed by the bottom activity

Comment: where ever you want place your `webview` .this  is the basic of `webview`. you can make fragments and there you can place your `webview` in your UI anywhere you want.

Comment: @ElimimianOsemaoje for accessing from bottom navigation you can use fragments check this  [bottom navigation view with fragments](https://medium.com/@oluwabukunmi.aluko/bottom-navigation-view-with-fragments-a074bfd08711)